# How to add several images to the stroke of a shape

Tags: wpf

I'm currently using multiple shapes to show something like a clock.
The clock can be an ellipse or a rectangle for example.

What I want to do, is to add some arrows that are represented as images. 
In total, four images should be added (at 12,3,6,9) and it should work despite any shape and any size of the shape.

I was thinking of doing some sort of binding where the image is in the stroke so each image should be binded to every direction that I mentionned before.

Comment: You should try something called as a template selector for this purpose

Comment: If these are just shapes with a single brush then Paths sound like they would be more appropriate than images. You can bind the data of a path to a geometry and switch that out in your viewmodel.  Grab those from resources.You could maybe put a grid in whatever your something-like-a-clock thing is and size that to the bounds of your shape. Then use horizontal and vertical alignment on your images/shapes so they're vertical top horizontal middle, bottom middle etc. Give them a margin to offset from the edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was thinking of doing some sort of binding where the image is in the stroke so each image should be binded to every direction that I mentionned before.

I would not recommend that, this will make it unnecessarily complicated. Use the given tools instead:

- XAML `Alignment`
- `ViewBox`
- XAML `RenderTransform`

Alignment:

There is a `HorizontalAlignment` and a `VerticalAlignment`, which can be used to keep an `Image` in place. For example the 12 oClock `Image`, the Alignment would be:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

This will keep the `Image` horizontally in the middle and always at the top.

Viewbox:

The `ViewBox` automatically scales its content to the `Size` of the `ViewBox`. This is very handy when the final `Size` is unknown or changes during run time.

Rendertransform:

A `RenderTransform` can change the appearance of an Element. In your case, a `RotateTransform` fits perfectly (as you can guess this rotates the Image of the Arrow).

Combine these things and you get a nice little Clock with this XAML

```
<!-- Add reference at the top of your XMAL -->
xmlns:mscorlib="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

<!-- ViewBox to adjust stretch/size of the clock automatically -->
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
    <!-- Grid container to hold all necessary elements for the Clock -->
    <Grid Height="100" Width="100">
        <!-- Shape for Clock (Background), can be a rectangle -->
        <Ellipse Fill="LightSkyBlue"/>

        <!-- 3 oClock Image -->
        <Image Source="/XAML;component/Assets/Images/Banana.ico" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="{DynamicResource PictureSize}" Width="{DynamicResource PictureSize}"/>
        <!-- 6 oClock Image -->
        <Image Source="/XAML;component/Assets/Images/Banana.ico" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="{DynamicResource PictureSize}" Width="{DynamicResource PictureSize}"/>
        <!-- 9 oClock Image -->
        <Image Source="/XAML;component/Assets/Images/Banana.ico" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="{DynamicResource PictureSize}" Width="{DynamicResource PictureSize}"/>
        <!-- 12 oClock Image -->
        <Image Source="/XAML;component/Assets/Images/Banana.ico" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="{DynamicResource PictureSize}" Width="{DynamicResource PictureSize}"/>

        <!-- Arrow for Hours, the height defines how "long" the arrow is (copy/paste for the seconds/minutes Arrow)-->
        <Image Source="/XAML;component/Assets/Images/Arrow.png" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,50" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <!-- Bind angle to a timer and update it every hour -->
                <RotateTransform Angle="30"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>

        <!-- Parameters to change appearance of clock (affects multiple elements)-->
        <Grid.Resources>
            <mscorlib:Double x:Key="PictureSize">20</mscorlib:Double>
        </Grid.Resources>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Which looks like this (sorry i just had no other image at hand than a banana)
[image]

Comment: That's a nice workaround, but the thing is that it could have been better to have each image depedent to the Ellipse and not the window. I marked it as an accepted answer anyway because that's good help.

Comment: It is dependent to the `ViewBox` not the `Window`. Furthermore the `Ellipse` is dependent to the `ViewBox` too, so the `Images` are indirectly dependent to the `Ellipse`. Just give it a try and set the `Size` of the `ViewBox` to fixed values like  `Height="300" Width="200"`

Comment: My bad! It's perfectly what I was looking for.